# Trying to login user via Azure AD fails in UWP

Tags: azure, win-universal-app, uwp

I am following this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-adal-sso-authentication/) to authenticate my user via AAD in my UWP. In the Portal I've made two AD registrations one web application 'testservice' and one native application 'testservicenative' where the testservicenative has permissions to testservice. I have assigned also in the 'testservice' the user that I want him to login. Here is the code that I wrote in my app:

```
            string clientId = "34324453-4354-4534-5454-4564565464";
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/testtenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            string resourceUri = "http://testservice.azurewebsites.net";
            string message;

            while (user == null)
            {               
                try
                {
                    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                    PlatformParameters par = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false);

                    AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, (Uri)null, par);
                    JObject payload = new JObject();
                    payload["access_token"] = ar.AccessToken;

                    user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
                    message = string.Format("You are now logged in - {0}", user.UserId);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    message = "You must log in. Login Required";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    message = "You must log in. Login Required";
                }
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
                dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
```

I am getting the AuthenticationResult with the data of my user and the authenticationtoke. However when the LoginAsync is called it throws an
InvalidOperationException with Message = "The request could not be completed.  (Unauthorized)"

1. Is the process and the code I wrote correct (The sample is for Windows 8 Store Apps)?
2. What might be the problem?

Comment: I think the issue lies with `(Uri)null` that you are passing to the `AcquireTokenAsync` method. Normally, you need to register the CallbackUri for the application in Azure AD. Then, you have to pass that same Uri to this method here. You can find the correct CallbackUri by calling `Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()`